# Save data to local storage AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

How can I save data in local storage and display it like in [here](https://api.github.com/users)?

Comment: I use: https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

Comment: You can try this : https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/grevory/angular-local-storage

go throught above link u need had angular local storage library then use set method to store data in local storage then u want to get data from local storage then use get method this above link demo also available for more reference